# Code to fill in array suddenly changes variable (C)

Tags: c, arrays, variables

I'm at the very beginning of learning to code, and have come up with the following problem that's left me scratching my head. at the second last input of the 'for' loop, 'control' suddenly becomes that input (tested by inserting a printf) any idea why, and what to do to avoid it (other than abandoning scanf)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sorting[], control,place, a,b,print;
int main()
{
    printf("Please enter how many numbers there are in total.\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    sorting[a];
    control=a-1;
    print=a;
    printf("Please start entering your numbers.\n");
    for(;print>0;print--)
    {
         scanf("%d",&sorting[print-1]);
    }
```

P.s. I know I've got an extra variable (print) when 'a' would do fine- I re-wrote that to see if the 'control=a' was somehow causing the problems.

Comment: What do you expect the statement `sorting[a];` to do?

Comment: [store-value-from-a-for-loop-into-an-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111372/store-value-from-a-for-loop-into-an-array)

Comment: declare the size of the array. But even if it's wrong, that's not causing the problem.

Comment: `int sorting[]` most probably does not define what you think it does.

Comment: @Michael, i think OP wants to give array size by using `sorting[a];`

Comment: Thanks Joachim. and all others

Comment: _"even if it's wrong, that's not causing the problem."_ It kind of is. You're expecting the array to have space for `a` elements after that, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `sorting` you declare it as an array of an unknown size. If you don't define the array anywhere the size will be one and any indexing above that will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior* (most likely overwriting other data, like variables).

There are two solutions to this, but I will only tell you one: Don't use global variables, and define the array after you get the size as input from the user. I.e.

```
scanf("%d",&a);
int sorting[a];
```

Comment: @alk Well that is the "proper" solution. I think you can guess what the other solution to *allocate* the array would be. :)

Comment: GCC, as an extension, assumes `int a[]` to have *one* element.

Comment: Thanks. I've chosen to avoid the global already, after seeing your answer before. I assume one answer is to just give a non-user defined value

Comment: @alk It is according to the C Standard that the array of incomplete type with external definition has type int[1] and its element is initialized by zero.

Answer (score 2):

In this (incomplete) program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sorting[], control,place, a,b,print;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
int main()
{
    printf("Please enter how many numbers there are in total.\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    sorting[a];
    control=a-1;
    print=a;
    printf("Please start entering your numbers.\n");
    for(;print>0;print--)
    {
         scanf("%d",&sorting[print-1]);
    }
```

array `sorting` has type `int [1]` (if it was not redeclared before the end of the translation unit and has incomplete type. It is not an array with a zero size as it is written in other answer). Thus this expression

```
sorting[a];
```

means an attempt to access memory beyond the array if `a` is greater than 0.

Instead of the external definition of the array `sorting` you could declare the array as a variable length array within main. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
int control,place, a,b,print;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
int main()
{
    printf("Please enter how many numbers there are in total.\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int sorting[a];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
    control=a-1;
    print=a;
    printf("Please start entering your numbers.\n");
    for(;print>0;print--)
    {
         scanf("%d",&sorting[print-1]);
    }
```